# How to make animation activity transition

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-activity

I am newbie in Android and i just started to make animations over activities. I am testing out and also learning this part carefully.
I have created several animations over activities, ex Zoom_in effect:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Zoom_out effect:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:zAdjustment="top">
    <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale=".5"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale=".5"
       android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

and so on... Then with `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);`

i called them and everything is working. Now i need help to make more advanced animation over activities, for example how can i make this animation that i saw in dribble, as I said i am newbie and if you help me making this i would be so happy :))

Link:
https://dribbble.com/shots/1942943-Product-purchase-transition?list=following&offset=0

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is not an activity transition, but i think it is a custom view or fragment that is added dynamically at runtime.

If you are targeting to Lollipop(API >= 21) you can find something similar in the android sdk. 
Please take a look at: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html in the section "authenthic motion" or
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html in the "reveal effect".